# Переменная со звуковым файлом: распечатать имя переменной и использовать его для сравнения

Tags: python

Добрый день! Подскажите пожайлуста как я могу сделать чтобы при случайном выборе переменной со звуковым файлом при использовании print(sound) не выводилось на экран что то вроде "[0x02E249B0>] и так далее а распечатывалось имя самой переменной которое я также в дальнейшем мог использовать для сравнения.

```
# English sound v.1
# Importing modules
import random
import pygame

#Basic settings
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([600, 400])
pygame.display.set_caption('English sound v.1')
keepGoing = True

#A list of sounds
#Consonant teams
ch = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ch.wav")
ck = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ck.wav")
dge = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/dge.wav")
while keepGoing:                        
    for event in pygame.event.get():    
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            keepGoing = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                sound = [ch,ck,dge]

                play_sound = random.choice(sound)
                play_sound.play()
                print (play_sound)
pygame.quit()
```

После случайного выбора переменной и проигрования звука я хочу производить ввод с клавиатуры сочетаний букв соответстующих звуку и чтобы переменная отображалась как посказка. А так же дальше использовать выбранную переменную. Надеюсь я смог объяснить.

Comment: либо добавьте словарь с именами переменных и печатайте не  `print (sound)`,  а `print (sounds[sound])`. Но сомнительна сама постановка вопроса...

Comment: если знаете английский  -  ответ здесь
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python#2553354

Comment: sound - в вашем примере - объект. Посмотрите через dir(sound) его свойства - может найдете нужный метод или свойство...
Короче - детализируйте вопрос.
ваш print (sound) печатает то, что дает метод \__str__  вашего объекта sound,  а вы что хотите напечатать?
Для сравнения можете использовать саму переменную, а не имя...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ваша функция.
Перебирает все имеющиеся переменные, находит идентичную параметру t и выдает его имя:

```
def name(t):
    for k, v in locals().items():
        if v is t:
            return k
```

Но повторюсь - что то не то с постановкой задачи ))
Вы всегда знаете имя переменной когда печатаете ее.
ИТОГО:
--- возможное решение:

```
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        sound = [(ch,'ch'), (ck, 'ck'), (dge,'dge')]
        play_sound = random.choice(sound)
        play_sound[0].play()
        print (play_sound[1])
```

Должно работать...

Comment: После случайного выбора переменной и проигрования звука я хочу производить ввод с клавиатуры сочетаний букв соответстующих звуку и чтобы переменная отображалась как посказка. А так же дальше использовать выбранную переменную. Надеюсь я смог объяснить.

Comment: Простите допустил ошибку, отображаться должна переменная случайно выбранная play_sound.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь все работает как надо.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно сравнивать имена переменных, просто сохраните их в словаре и вызывайте по ключу.

```
sounds = {
    "ch": pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ch.wav"),
    "ck": pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ck.wav"),
    "dge": pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/dge.wav"),
}
```

соответственно теперь вы можете просто вызвать `sounds['имя']`